# How to EDIT data which is coming from a formula/FILTER ,QUERY OR IMPORT or by a function in google sheets

Tags: javascript

I am actually curious about it that is it possible that we can edit a data range or column which is coming from a function or import range ?query or filter ?
i have a sheet on which data is coming through a import range function i want to edit the data here manually according to the need
Also a function script is there from which data is coming to this sheet
codes are here -

```
const masterSheet = "ASM-A11";
const masterSheetFormulaCell = "A2";
const ignoreSheets = ["Verified NDRx","Business Tracker","NDRX","PMT_EBx","PMT_EBx.","NDRx PMT Business Tracker.","Analysis"];
const dataRange = "A2:AA";
const checkRange = "A2:A" ;
//end set variables

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;

ignoreSheets.push(masterSheet) ;

const allsheets = ss.getSheets() ;

const filteredListofSheets = allsheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

let formulaArray = filteredListofSheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange},"${s.getSheetName()} - Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange})}, '${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRange}<>"")`);
let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";")+ "}"

//console.1og( formulaText) ;
ss. getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell) .setFormula(formulaText) ;

}
```